# Convert `NSDate` to `NSString`, e.g., @"11:22am"?

Tags: ios, localization, nsstring, nsdate, nsdateformatter

How do I convert the time of an `NSDate` to an `NSString`, e.g., `@"11:22am"`? How do I support all locales?

Answer (score 4):

You need to use NSDateFormatter, preferably using one of the [NSDateFormatterStyle](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSDateFormatterNoStyle) constants, who's value will be different depending on the locale of the user (USA/UK/Australia all have different short date formats for example).

```
NSDateFormatter *timeFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle];
[dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];

NSString *timeString = [timeFormatter stringFromDate:date];
```

Answer (score 2):

Use for this `NSDateFormatter`:

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss zzz"];//HH:mm

NSString *strDate = [formatter stringFromDate:myDate];
```

Comment: this technique will not allow you to support different locales.